# How to restore the packages from my own server instead of nuget.org in asp5?

Tags: macos, nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package-restore, dnu

Is it possible to restore the packages from own server instead of nuget.org site in asp 5 application ?

suppose i have package called **mynewpackage** which i have added in dependencies in project.json file. i have to restore this packages from own server instead of nuget.org site when do **dnu restore**

please suggest me an idea to do this

-Guru

Comment: Sure, if you [run your own nuget server](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to install a nuget repository to your server. You can follow the step described [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/wiki/Hosting-the-NuGet-Gallery-Locally-in-IIS)

Then open Visual Studio and go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings

Then add your nuget repository as you see in the image below, and you are ready

[image]